Ubuntu Server 24.04 regression. systemd-logind spikes to 100% CPU usage
It's a server-laptop.  sudo systemctl status systemd-logind does not give any new output. It is related to the lid being closed. Fans start to spin just as I close the lid.
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleSuspendKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

Tried everything I found on the internet, also:
systemd-logind uses 80-90% CPU
One issue I noticed, if I open the server itself I get many logs like this:
ucsi_acpi USBC000:000 con121: failed to get status
ucsi_acpi USBC000:000 con121: possible UCSI driver bug 2

and it awaits for me to type the login and pass. Might be related.

After months of trying to find a fix, I went berserk and removed the closing lid event.
To find the exact event number your should check the logs after restarting the service.
sudo service systemd-logind restart
sudo service systemd-logind status

Find the event associated with Closing Lid Sensor and remove it. In my case:
sudo rm /dev/input/event2
sudo service systemd-logind restart

